# Does summing divergent series using cutoff functions give consistent results?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory, divergent-series

One way to try to give a value $S$ to a divergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is with a smooth cutoff function:
$$
S = \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \eta\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)
$$
where $\eta(0)=1$, and $\eta$ has some smoothness conditions (at least continuous at 0, possibly more, e.g. $C^1$ or $C^\infty$) and some asymptotic decay conditions (e.g. $\eta$ is compactly supported or decays exponentially).

Are there any nice **consistency results** about such approaches? For example, is the following statement true (potentially with some conditions on $\eta$ or $a_n$ if necessary):

> *Claim*: If $\eta$ and $\tilde{\eta}$ both lead to well-defined values $S$ and $\tilde{S}$ for the above limit, then $S=\tilde{S}$.

(Or perhaps even "If any $\eta$ gives rise to a well-defined value $S$ for a series, then some particular stronger summation method M also ascribes $S$ to the series" in the same way that convergence of any Norlund mean forces a generalized Abel sum to exist and have that value.)

---

*Context*: Coming from a physics background, this seems one of the most natural approaches to take. And barring some small caveats it nicely encapsulates other approaches like Abel summation ($\eta(x) = e^{-x}$) and Cesaro summation ($\eta(x) = (1-x)_+$) and normal summation ($\eta(x) = \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$); note these do have such a consistency result. But surprisingly, there seems a massive dearth of mathematical literature about this general class of approaches. (In particular, I've skimmed Hardy's Divergent Series and didn't spot anything about it.) In fact, Terry Tao's [classic blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/) on the subject seems to be almost the sole reference! So another obvious question is simply: are there any good discussions of this family of approaches out there?

---

*Additional Thoughts (31/12/2023):* One natural way to think about this problem is to look at the 'simplest' non-trivial divergent $a_n$ possible, which is probably Grandi's series, $a_n = (-1)^{n-1}$. Some observations:

- As mentioned by [Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/), if $\eta$ is compactly supported and $C^1$ (in fact I think it suffices to be continuous and piecewise $C^1$), then you necessarily get convergence and it necessarily gives $S = \frac{1}{2}$. (I also suspect you can weaken the compact support condition somewhat but haven't tried to prove this.)
- Obviously with the conventional discontinuous $\eta(x) = \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$ this does not converge to anything.
- If you take $\eta(x) = \mathbb{1}_{[0,2]}(x)$, and only consider $N=1,2,3,\ldots$ to take discrete values, then you can obtain $S = 0$. This definitely feels against the spirit of things, but it is an important point to bear in mind.
- Less obviously, I can't see an easy way to construct a discontinuous $\eta$ which leads to convergence to any $S$ *if* you assume that you take $N$ to vary continuously.

This suggests it's helpful to think about a weaker statement along the lines of *(1) all sufficiently smooth $\eta$ agree* and a stronger conjecture that *(2) all $\eta$ agree if $N$ is taken to vary continuously*.

It seems plausible that more familiar arguments like Tao's (based around the Euler-Maclaurin formula) or something involving Mellin transforms can prove a weaker claim along the lines of (1), at least for some restricted class like $a_n = O(n^k)$ for any $k$ (and then if $\eta$ is taken to be e.g. $C^k$ and piecewise $C^{k+1}$ and to decay exponentially you can prove convergence to e.g. the same value as the Abel sum).

The stronger claim (2) then may fail to be true, or perhaps it is possible to disprove that convergence to any $S$ is possible for insufficiently smooth (or perhaps insufficiently rapidly decaying) $\eta$. Or perhaps you can even somehow arrange for convergence but only to a consistent value of $S$.

It would be interesting to see proofs or counterexamples for any of the above statements.

Comment: A quick and easy observation is that summing a series via a cutoff function has an incomparable strength to the analytical continuation (i.e. there exists series that don't have analytical continuations but can be summed via a cutoff function ( true for essentially any cutoff function), and there exists sums that can be evaluated with analytical continuation but not with cutoff functions (This is true for the cutoff functions I know, but perhaps not in general)).
[Continued in the next comment]

Comment: [Continued]
I mention this only because it's tempting to analyze divergent series summation in terms of its connection to analytical continuation, but that technique won't give you general results, because analytical continuation is too weak to cover all the cases summation of divergent series can cover.
Consider for instance 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n \frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$$
which typically has a natural boundary at the unit circle. If we take $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq 0$ then the sum doesn't converge outside, but choosing something slow-growing like $n^k$ makes it cutoff-convergent.

Comment: Of course compare the classical study of divergent series, e.g. Hardy's book.  Fit your schemes into the ones discussed there.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thanks, but I mention having quickly read through Hardy and not having seen any result there which would help answer the general question raised here. (The consistency of conventional summation, Cesaro and Abel which I mention is of course classical and easily found in Hardy. That was also my reference for the comment about Norlund means.) Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 5):

Tao's "smoothed sums" can be seen as a particular class of so-called *matrix summation methods* in the modern (post-Hardy) literature, see e.g. J. Boos, *Classical and Modern Methods in Summability* (Oxford University Press, 2001) and references therein. For such methods, there are indeed consistency theorems which I'll detail shortly.

In what follows, let $$\omega = \mathbb{K}^\mathbb{N} = \left\{x=(x_n)=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{K}\right\}$$ be the vector space of all $\mathbb{K}$-valued sequences (here $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), $$c = \left\{x\in\omega\ \middle|\ \lim x\doteq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n\text{ exists}\right\}$$ the subspace of all *convergent* sequences, $$c_s = \left\{x\in\omega\ \middle|\ \Sigma\,x\doteq\left(\sum^n_{k=1}x_k\right)\in c\right\}=\left\{x\in\omega\ \middle|\ \lim\Sigma\,x\doteq\sum^\infty_{n=1}x_n\text{ exists}\right\}$$ the subspace of all *summable* sequences, and $$l^1 = \left\{x\in\omega\ \middle|\ |x|\doteq\left(|x_n|\right)\in c_s\right\}$$ the subspace of all *absolutely summable* sequences, so that $l^1\subset c_s\subset c\subset\omega$ (recalling that $x\in c_s$ implies that $\lim x=0$). Put differently, $c$ is the domain of the *limit* (linear) functional $\lim$ and $c_s=\Sigma^{-1}(c)$, where $\Sigma$ is the *partial sum* linear map, which may be seen as the infinite matrix $$\Sigma=\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & \ddots \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & \ddots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots \end{array}\right]\ .$$ Many (linear) summability techniques are based on functional analysis and see the summability problem as a (continuous) *extension* problem for the *series sum* (continuous) linear functional $\lim\Sigma$ as defined e.g. in the Banach space $l^1$ to a larger locally convex vector (sequence) space $l^1\subset X\subset\omega$. Such an extension always exists by the Hahn-Banach theorem, so we want a *constructive* version of that result in this particular context.

The starting point of a matrix summation method is to replace $\Sigma$ with another infinite matrix (likewise identified with the corresponding linear map) $$A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \ddots \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & \ddots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots\end{array}\right]$$ such that:

- $X$ is contained in the domain of $A$, that is, $$X\subset\left\{x\in\omega\ \middle|\ Ax\doteq\left(\lim\Sigma\,(a_{nk}x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\text{ exists}\right\}\ ;$$
- $AX\subset c$, so that $\lim Ax$ exists for all $x\in X$;
- At the very least, $\lim A$ extends $\lim\Sigma$ from $$\varphi=\mathbb{K}^{(\mathbb{N})}=\left\{x\in\omega\ \middle|\ \exists k\in\mathbb{N}:x_n=0\ \forall n\geq k\right\}\subset l^1\ ,$$ the subspace of *finitely non-zero* sequences, to $X$, that is, $\varphi\subset X$ and $\lim Ax=\lim\Sigma\,x$ for all $x\in\varphi$.

There are additional conditions which are discussed e.g. in Boos's book quoted above, but these will not matter in what follows. As a rule, $A$ is chosen first and then $X$ is determined from $A$ and the above conditions - one usually gets a Fréchet sequence space. In the case of smoothed sums with respect to a given cutoff function $\eta$, the matrix $A$ is given by $a_{nk}=\eta\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$, $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Within such a framework, a *consistency theorem* is a statement of the following kind: let matrices $A,B$ as above with corresponding sequence subspaces $X_A,X_B$ playing the role of $X$ for each of these, and let $x\in (X_A\cap X_B)\smallsetminus\varphi$.

> **Theorem (consistency of $A,B$ on $Y$):** Suppose $(\lim A)|_{\varphi\oplus\mathbb{K}x}=(\lim B)|_{\varphi\oplus\mathbb{K}x}$. Then there is a sequence subspace $\varphi\oplus\mathbb{K}x\subsetneqq Y\subset X_A\cap X_B$ such that $(\lim A)|_Y=(\lim B)|_Y$.

Section 2.6 and Chapters 9-10 of Boos's book are entirely dedicated to such results.

As a final remark, I would like to stress that the similarity of the above discussion with renormalization ideas in quantum field theory is no accident: as pointed by Klaus Hepp long ago, perturbative renormalization in quantum field theory (with an infrared cutoff in the interaction) is nothing more than constructively extending the distributions corresponding to Feynman graphs, which are usually only defined in a (usually finite-codimensional) subspace of test functions. To directly quote (see pp. 302 of K. Hepp, *Proof of the Bogoliubov-Parasiuk Theorem on Renormalization*, Commun. Math. Phys. **2** (1966) 301-326):

> The renormalization theory (...) is in this framework a constructive form of the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: Is it possible to ask you to add a caricature of one or two of the type of consistency theorems that show up in Boos's book?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I don't have access to the book at the minute, so any concrete result you could quote from it that answers one of my questions would be great. But I will note a couple of things: (1) I was more concerned with whether there *can be any discrepancies* (in $X_A \cap X_B \setminus Y$ so to speak) and therefore as an example (2) it would be good to know what is "wrong" in my silly example of inconsistently summing Grandi's series by taking partial sums of 1, 3, 5,... elements vs 2, 4, 6,... elements.

Comment: @WillieWong I'll try to do that in the next few days, as time allows...

Comment: @notallwrong I'll try as well to translate some instances of the consistency theorems Willie asked for above into the language of cutoff functions. I don't mind losing the bounty due to time. Regarding your points (1) and (2), I believe that what goes wrong in your example is that typically consistency theorems imply some convergence conditions for the matrix elements that seem at first glance to be violated in your case. I'll try to clarify that as well within the next few days...

Comment: Oh, I've just awarded you the bounty anyway, you may as well have it, that's not important. It's nice to have the reference anyway and it's only a small bounty.

Comment: Worth saying that I'm particularly interested in series like $1-2+3-4+\cdots$ which behave quite badly, and trying to understand whether cutoff functions give a nice, natural way to canonically define them.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro Don't suppose you've had a chance to look at the known consistency results and see if they can help answer the general questions I posed?

Comment: @notallwrong sorry, I was on a short vacation... I'll make the promised update to my answer by this Friday at the latest.

Comment: Hi @PedroLauridsenRibeiro, have you had any thoughts by any chance?